# want to make UI like android's recent call list in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make UI like android mobile's RECENT phone call list where all calls with same date remain in a container and Header with Date Title,

I have a list of transaction and to Make such UI
I have created a local List of transaction named **temp** and a bool variable named **showContainer**..

I am adding transaction to this **temp** list until date found mismatched..

its working fine but i think taking this extra list of temp is not right way of coding..

Is there any other good way to make **this without using any packages...**

I just want to do with Logically...

```
List<Trans> temp = [];
  bool showContainer = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final trans = data[index];
                if (index == 0) temp.add(trans);

                String previousDate = index > 0
                    ? DateFormat('yMMMMd').format(data[index - 1].date)
                    : '';

                String currentDataDate =
                    DateFormat('yMMMMd').format(data[index].date);

                if (previousDate != currentDataDate) {
                  showContainer = true;
                } else {
                  temp.add(trans);
                  showContainer = false;
                }

                return Column(
                  children: [
                    if (currentDataDate != previousDate)
                      Container(
                        //Date Title Container
                        height: 40,
                        child: Center(child: Text(currentDataDate.toString())),
                      ),
                    if (showContainer)
                      Container(
                        // Showing Transaction Container
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                            color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                        child: Column(
                          children: List.generate(
                            temp.length,
                            (index) => CustomTransTileWidget(
                              showDivider: index != temp.length - 1,
                              trans: temp[index],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  ],
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

trans class

```
class Trans
{
  String id;
  double amount;
  String title;
  bool isExpense;
  DateTime date;
  Trans({required this.id,required this.title,this.isExpense=false,required this.amount,required this.date});
}

List<Trans> data=[
  Trans(id: '1', title: 'Food', amount: 100.0, date: DateTime(2023,08,01)),
  Trans(id: '2', title: 'Food', amount: 130.0, date: DateTime(2023,08,01)),
  Trans(id: '3', title: 'Food', amount: 150.0, date: DateTime(2023,08,01)),
  Trans(id: '4', title: 'Food', amount: 300.0, date: DateTime(2023,08,02),isExpense: false),
  Trans(id: '5', title: 'Food', amount: 200.0, date: DateTime(2023,08,02))
];
```

[image]

Comment: Show code for `Trans` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to group your transactions by their date, because you want to display them as a group.

Using this input data:

```
List<Trans> data = [
  Trans(id: '1', title: 'Food', amount: 100.0, date: DateTime(2023, 08, 01)),
  Trans(id: '2', title: 'Food', amount: 130.0, date: DateTime(2023, 08, 01)),
  Trans(id: '3', title: 'Food', amount: 150.0, date: DateTime(2023, 08, 01)),
  Trans(
      id: '4',
      title: 'Food',
      amount: 300.0,
      date: DateTime(2023, 08, 02),
      isExpense: false),
  Trans(id: '5', title: 'Food', amount: 200.0, date: DateTime(2023, 08, 02))
];
```

Since you don't want to use any packages, I will provide the following `groupListsBy` source from the package https://pub.dev/packages/collection.

```
/// Author: https://pub.dev/packages/collection
extension ListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  /// Groups elements into lists by [keyOf].
  Map<K, List<T>> groupListsBy<K>(K Function(T element) keyOf) {
    var result = <K, List<T>>{};
    for (var element in this) {
      (result[keyOf(element)] ??= []).add(element);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

(optional) In order to make the comparison work by date, ignoring the time components, then you want to remove any time components that might be present in the real data.:

```
extension DateTimeExtension on DateTime {
  DateTime removeTimeComponents() {
    return DateTime(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

An alternative to the above is to create your own custom compare function. Either way, with those two utility methods, we can group transactions by date:

```
final groups = data.groupListsBy((t) => t.date.removeTimeComponents());
```

Output:

```
[log] groups: {2023-08-01 00:00:00.000: [1, 2, 3], 2023-08-02 00:00:00.000: [4, 5]}
```

You can think of the UI for this as a list of lists. A list of dates, and each date leads to a list of transactions (see comments):

```
return ListView(
  children: [
    /// Dart pattern matching to destructure the MapEntry.
    for (final MapEntry(key: date, value: transactions) in groups.entries)

      /// For each date, generate a column with the date and a list of
      /// transactions.
      Column(
        children: [
          /// Column title.
          Text(date.toString()),

          /// List of transactions for date.
          ListView(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              for (final transaction in transactions)
                ListTile(
                  title: Text(transaction.title),
                  subtitle: Text(transaction.amount.toString()),
                ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
  ],
);
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer....with very good explaination.....Thank you very much..Its not only solution to my question but learnt many more things to deal code like advance level......

Comment: my basic code worked fine but wanted to know advance level and u given...here is one more question....does it matter how we code? like ur and mine...how to check which code is best for performanace...is there any way to check?

Comment: In my opinion, code should focus on being as clear as possible (easy to understand for yourself *and* others). By using the grouping function, you express the intent of grouping by dates through the sorting function. A `temp` array doesn't really say much about the intention of the operation... what exactly is temporary? You would have to go read the code, follow what it is doing and figure out what `temp` is doing. For performance, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/testing/integration/profiling